# trying to connect to my database in my localhost but keep getting an error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, localhost

```
 < ?php
     $connection = mysql_connect(localhost","user","password") or die ("Couldn't connect to the server!");
     mysql_select_db("users", $connection) or die ("Couldn't connect to the database!");
```

I used the above code above to try and connect to my database but keep getting an error in line 2 where `mysql_connect(localhost)----` I've typed in my localhost name correctly why won't it work?

please help this is my first day ever dealing with php and databases.
thanks in advance.

Comment: It usually helps if you look at the actual error message: http://php.net/mysql_error (sigh, and here was me assuming that since you didn't say what error message you were getting, it was because you were getting *Couldn't connect to the server!*)

Comment: `localhost` needs to be quoted fully. You are missing the opening quote. `"localhost"`

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: And whitespace must not appear in `<?php` (though I suspect that could be a typographical problem only when posting here>

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski if that was the issue the PHP parser wouldn't have started and he would not be getting any errors at all.

Comment: @MOHAMEDAHMED Post your actual code. As in copy/paste. If that IS infact your code you need to first fix the two things that have been pointed out to you.

Comment: The only reason to edit the actual code is to remove your user or pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing a quote in localhost:

```
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","user","password") or die ("Couldn't connect to the server!");
```

Comment: the "localhost" still is highlighted in red and when I load up the page i get "opject not found!"  "Error 404"

Comment: @MOHAMEDAHMED are you running the script from a webserver or locally?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is:

```
<?php
$connexion = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password")
    or die("Couldn't connect to the database! : " . mysql_error());
mysql_close($connexion);
?>
```

**Nota Bene:**

Rather use `mysqli_` or `PDO.` What you are using here is deprecacted for security reasons.